# Optimizar sintetizado de voz cuando se usa reconocimiento de voz en uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, optimización, windows10

Que tal mi problema es el siguiente: ME encuentro elaborando un software en Universal App (Windows 10) para telefonos el cual usa sintetizado y reconocimiento de voz para interactuar con el usuario, pero cuando pruebo el software en mi dispositivo (Lumia 830) el software falla ya que cuando se activa el sintetizador se congela en ciertas frases como por ejemplo "Say a Command" y termina diciendo "say a Commmaaaaaaaaaaaand"... Es un dolor de cabeza pues hice muchas pruebas y determine que eso sucede cuando empleo el sintetizado y reconocimiento de voz en una instruccion.. Sin embargo probe separandolas en clases distintas (es programacion asincrona ojo C#) y sigue dando el mismo problema..: OJO en el emulador funciona perfecto... Escucho sus sugerencias, gracias.
Este es mi codigo:

```
 sin.Voice = (SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Male));

    var language = new Windows.Globalization.Language("en-EN");

    SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(language);



    List<string> dict= new List<string>();


    string[] responses = { "One", "Twoo", "three", "End", "Exit", };


    var listConstraint = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(responses, "Comandos");


    recognizer.Constraints.Add(listConstraint);
    await recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

    var recognition = recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

    //await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, new DispatchedHandler(
    //   () => { mediaElement.Stop(); mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType); mediaElement.Play(); }));
    texto = "     " + "    " + "Say a COmmand" + "     " + "    ";
    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await sin.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(texto);


    if (mediaElement.CurrentState.Equals(MediaElementState.Playing))
    {
        mediaElement.Stop();
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();

    }else
    {
        //mediaElement.Stop();
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();

    }



    recognition.Completed += this.Recognition_Completed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pronta solución ha sido añadir pausas con comas y puntos y espacios en blanco a fin de evitar estos tartamudeos que son sumamente molestos para el usuario.
Ejemplo

```
texto = " ....Say a COmmand....  ";
```